# print list in proper way python

Tags: python, list

I have a list  "values" it has the types information i just to print it properly

in ipython notebook i am trying to print

case1:

```
> print values 
[<type 'str'>, <type 'str'>, <type 'str'>, <type 'str'> <type 'int'>]
```

case2:but if i simply do

```
 >values
  [str, str, str, str, int]
```

Ultimately i just **case2**  way of printing and tried to do it many ways but not getting it.

Comment: What part are you having difficulty with? Don't know how to get the string `'str'` from the type object `str`? Don't know how to comma-separate a sequence of strings?

Comment: i am having problem with the first part, i want the output in form of second part [str, str, str, str, int]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a list of type objects, and both `__str__` and `__repr__` of type objects have a `<type 'x'>` form.

If you want to print list of names of type objects you need to perform conversion manually:

```
print [t.__name__ for t in values]
```